# Execute multiple stored procedures with single trip to database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, azure-sql-database

I have a lot of legacy data access code mainly SqlCommand with Stored Procedure calls that we used to execute alot of Insert statment into an database. 
As long as the SQL server has been on the same machine as the application there have been acceptable performace but now are we trying to move some of the data to SQL Azure.

The problem is that our code calls a SP for every record to insert which results in quite a few trips to the database and when not located on the same server it takes some time.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("connString")
var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn, "spMyStoreProc");
cmd.Params.Add("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
cmd.Params.Add("@b", SqlDbType.Int);

using(conn)
{
 conn.Open();
 foreach(var rec in recordsToInsert)
 {
   cmd.Parameters["@a"].Value = rec.A;
   cmd.Parameters["@b"].Value = rec.B;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 conn.Close();
}
```

I have tried the code above with and without Transactions.

I have also tried to use a "batch" SQL statement to execute several SPs in every trip to the server.
Like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC spMyStoreProc @a='a' @b=2; EXEC spMyStoreProc @a='b' @b=4;"
```

It greatly increases the performance of the operation but since I have quite a few SPs where every SP has about 20-50 params it gets quite tedious to write this code for all the insert commands in this data access component.

Is this the best way to achive this, or can I somehow tell ADO.NET I want to execute my calls as a batch (havent fount anything suggesting its possible but feel that I atleast should ask) to avoid network latency etc betweeen every single SP call?

If not does anybody know any good way to achive this without having to write it "by hand" and since its a legacy application I can not change the data layer completely.
Is there any applications that can take SqlCommands with parameters and generate the TQL they would execute?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have one stored procedure, that calls all the other stored procedures - it will probably be the least amount of work. So, from the code you only call the stored procedures once... so given that they are the same parameters you are passing every time (because your code seems to imply that) you would basically do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RunBatch(@param1, @param2, etc [all the parameters you need])
AS

exec spMyStoreProc @a='a'
exec spMyStoreProc2 @b='b'
```

The advantages of this are many, some of which being that its all centralized, and you can even wrap all of them within a transaction, so as not to do dirty inserts (given that they all depend on each other).

Also, if you don't feel like passing 20/30 parameters to each SP, you may want to make a user-table-defined data-type for each set of parameters, that you can pass. So then each SP gets 1 or 2 parameters, and the code becomes much simpler and readable.

EDIT:

This is a good reference for the user-defined table types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

And this is how to pass the table valued types to SQL server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: Actually the parameters differ quite a bit between the calls so the first solution to use a wrapper SP doesnt really solve my "problem".
I will look into the table approach, it seem like a interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to M.R.'s approach would be to send all your parameters as an XML document, then parse the XML document to extract your parameters. This may simplify the interface a bit.

However I think you were on something when you discussed the possibility of chaining all the commands in a single string. But instead of manually building them, consider building an extension method to the SqlCommand object that returns a single string for execution, leveraging the sp_executesql syntax, and execute the entire string in a single pass.

So you would have a loop that looks like this, and you would call a new ToInlineSql extension method:

```
string sqlCommand = "";
foreach(var rec in recordsToInsert) 
{   cmd.Parameters["@a"].Value = rec.A;   
    cmd.Parameters["@b"].Value = rec.B;
    sqlCommand += cmd.ToInlineSql(); 
}
// execute sqlCommand
```

The ToInlineSql extension method could look like this (peuso-code, you will have to add certain things such as checking for the data type and so on) [and here is the link to [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
public static class SqlCmdExt 
{
      public static string ToInlineSql(this SqlCommand cmd)
      {
            string sql = "sp_executesql " + cmd.CommandText  ;
            foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
            {
                  sql += ", @" + p.Name + " " + p.DataType.ToString() ;
                  sql += ", " + p.Name + " = " + p.Value;
            }
            sql += ";";
            return sql;
      }
}
```